# Roundup using math

Tags: c#, msdn

I have a amount 100001, i want to round it up to nearest 10000.
my expected output after roundup would be 110000.

How to do that using c#??

Comment: You are not rounding, but ceiling. Rounding would give you 100000.

Answer (score 0):

```
double c = Math.Ceiling( 100001 / 1000 ) * 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works given the test case:

```
double RoundUp(double value, double factor) {
    return Math.Ceiling(value / factor) * factor;
}
```

Usage:

```
var answer = RoundUp(100001, 10000);
```

Answer:

> 110000

Comment: Care to explain downvotes? Please give the test case where it does not work.

Comment: @L.B Err, OK. whatever :-)